# Set<String> getSet(String s)

Tags: java, string, set

I am suppose to be returning a set from a Hashmap that I have created and should be located in the hashmap, but for whatever reason it is not currently working. Here is my method:

```
public Set<String> getSet(String s){
    // returns the Set<String> that is associated with the String s
    String stand = standardize(s);

    if(check(stand)){

        System.out.println(map.get(stand));

    }

    return null;

}
```

We also had a list ,but me converted it into a map. Standardize changes a string into alphabetical order  which makes a string out of it. This string is used as a key. I am trying to print out that set, but for whatever reason it isn't working. What am I doing wrong? P.S. this code is in Java.

Comment: You haven't posted enough here for us to help you.

Comment: map basically is a Hashmap which contains all the sets that have keys, check basically checks the code if the standardize version of the key is there. If it is map.get(stand) should print out the set, the current set I am using in this code is a treeset. Anything else I should cover? I am sry about how I left somethings out :( I am new to code. :) I will try my best. Just ask a question and hopefully I can answer that

Comment: Please read [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://www.sscce.org/) and [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
return map.get(stand);
```

Answer (score 0):

without more details of `standardize(s)` and `check(s)` it would be hard to guess. If `check(s)`, as the name suggests, checks whether the map contains `s` as a key, then  most likely the issue comes from `standadize(s)`. Here is an example how things should work smoothly:

```
static HashMap<String,Set<String>> map=new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
public static void main(String[] args) {

  TreeSet<String> set1=new TreeSet<String>();
  set1.add("Zoralikecury");
  set1.add("Xline");
  set1.add("XYZ");
  map.put("1", set1);
  map.put("2", null);
    System.out.println(getSet("1"));

}

public static Set<String> getSet(String s){
    if(check(s))
        return map.get(s);
  return null;
}
public static boolean check(String s)
{
   Iterator<String>it= map.keySet().iterator();
   while(it.hasNext())
   if(it.next().equals(s))
       return true;
   return false;
}
```